# Change Post Title Color dynamically in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, colors, title

i want to change post title color dynamically like this

```
<h3 class="green">Post title 1</h3>
<p>post Text</p>

<h3 class="blue">Post title 1</h3>
<p>post Text</p>

<h3 class="orange">Post title 1</h3>
<p>post Text</p>

<h3 class="red">Post title 1</h3>
<p>post Text</p>

<h3 class="yello">Post title 1</h3>
<p>post Text</p>
```

I limit posts_per_pge = 5, so when a new post ad its title color change in GREEN

Any idea how can i do this any........idea

Comment: You mean that you want to attach a different class to the post title for every 5 posts in a row?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by simply as:
first add a custom field with each post and decide which color for that post title
[image]

now just get this meta field in your query and change title style

```
<h2 style="color:<?php echo $meta_color; ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?> </h2>
```

may this help you...

Answer (score 1):

Count post with a variable and when its 5 return to zero. Then use that to echo diffetent classes. For example something like:

```
$post_count=0;
$class = "";
if (have_posts() ){....
$post_count .= 1;

if($post_count == 1) $class = "green";
// same with 2, 3, 4 and so on

<h3 class="<? echo $class; ?>">title</h3>      
<p>post Text</p> 

if($post_count == 4) $post_count = 0;

}// end loop
```

Comment: thanx alot @rgdesign its very helpful to me......two answers are very helpfull yours and Valerius

Answer (score 1):

While Dk-Macadamias solution is a bit more flexible (allowing you to change color on a per-post basis) a more automatic alternative would be to let the post order decide and output the color from a predetermined array.

In your template file:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<h3 class="<?php echo get_post_color_class(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

In your functions.php

```
function get_post_color_class() { //Declare our custom function
  global $wp_query; //Import the global $wp_query object
  $colors = array('green','blue','orange','red','yellow'); //Declare our array of colors

  return $colors[$wp_query->current_post]; //Return the item in our array with the same index as the current post in the loop
}
```

Comment: thanx alot @Valerius its very helpful to me......two answers are very helpfull yours and rgdesign

Answer (score 1):

If you want to alter between two colors you can do it like this. This function will actually count at all posts on a page and not look at the global post ID

```
function get_post_color_class() { //Declare our custom function
  global $wp_query; //Import the global $wp_query object
  $colors = array('#D8D32B','#D12F4E'); //Declare our array of colors
  return $colors[($wp_query->current_post % 2 != 0) ? 0 : 1];
  //Return the item in our array with the same index as the current post in the loop
}
```

In my case I wanted to alter and change the border-color of a post in wordpess. I did it like this in the content.php:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( ); ?>
style="border-left-color:<?php echo get_post_color_class(); ?>" >
```

More than two colors goes like this:

```
function get_post_color_class() { //Declare our custom function
  global $wp_query; //Import the global $wp_query object
  $colors = array('#D8D32B','#D12F4E', '#009562'); //Declare our array of colors
  if($wp_query->current_post % 3 == 0){
     return $colors[2];
  }

  if($wp_query->current_post % 2 == 0){
     return $colors[1];
  }
  return $colors[0];
}
```

Alternativly you could resolve it with CSS:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp

This should be more elegant and faster.